# Wampserver C++ CGI Script 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, cgi, msys2

I am using gcc compiler to compile both C and C++ CGI scripts. My C CGI script works just fine. However, I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error for running C++ CGI scripts. Here is my C++ code:

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
    cout << "<h1>Hello, C++!</h1>\n";

    return 0;
}
```

---

Please help! I have been desperately trying this for more than 24 hours. I have searched Google, Youtube, and even ChatGPT for help, but no luck. Thank you.

Comment: Don't use gcc for C++ programs, use g++ instead.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code of course. Whatever issue you are having it is caused by something else.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the shown code. Therefore, the problem must be somewhere else. P.S. ChatGPT is just a dumb bot. Relying on dumb bot for C++ reference is like relying on a parrot for learning English.

Comment: I used g++ and c++ compilers as well. They didn't work either. Same error.

Comment: @Nick I think the most likely problem would be a failure of your executable to locate a necessary shared library (or DLL) when it executes. Try linking statically with the C++ runtime.

Comment: You can try looking into the logs of the web server if it has any details about the error. Also try running the binary by hand if it actually runs...

Comment: I figured it out. I was using the newest version of gnu collection of compilers (gcc, g++, and c++), versions 13.1.0. I switched back to 12.2.0, the previous version. They all work (gcc, g++, and c++) with the older versions 12.2.0. The newer versions are still giving me the 500 Internal Server Error. So, this error still exists with the newest version 13.1.0. However, I can still at least work with 12.2.0. Thank you everyone for your time.

Comment: I have fixed the issue. i upgraded msys2 with pacman -Suy using ucrt64. It said there were issues with a couple of packages so it reinstalled the packages on its own. Then, exited ucrt64 terminal and reopened ucrt64. I updated again using pacman Suy to see if there were any additional updates. It was up to date. Then I changed back to the newest version of gcc compilers 13.1.0 by setting back the path of  the newest versions 13.1.0 with edit environment variables. It now works with the newest versions 13.1.0. I guess this case can be closed now.